# get dynamic link with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am creating a div dynamically. In that div, i have table. Table contains link in each 1st td of row.

My link id looks like

id="ac2dc332-fa95-4e59-a3ad-83ffa91d3f4d#Apple#APPLCCompanies"

Now, depending on some condition, i need to change color of this link.

i tried to get it through $('#ac2dc332-fa95-4e59-a3ad-83ffa91d3f4d#Apple#APPLCCompanies').attr("color","green") but i am not able to get this link.

If id can have any limitation, i can simply put small word as "Name" attribute for link but is it possible to get link by name?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: to change the text color, use: `.css('color', 'green')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$('[name="myName"]')](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEquals#attributevalue)

Comment: i m trying to change color
$('[name="SBCATTCompanies"]').attr("color", "green");
without success

Comment: I think you're looking for `.css('color', 'green')`

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem might be that you have hashes (#) in your ID. You could try escaping them:

```
$('#ac2dcblahblah\\#Apple\\#APPLblah');
```

> **Special characters in selectors**
>
> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters described above as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with a backslash (). Since Javascript uses the backslash for escape sequences in string literals, you must use two backslashes (\) in string literals so that a single backslash will be put into the string 1.
>
> Example:
>
> `"#foo\\:bar"`
>   `"#foo\\[bar\\]"`
>   `"#foo\\.bar"`
>
> The full list of characters that need to be escaped: `#;&,.+*~':"!^$[]()=>|/`

...but I think a better solution would be to not use that character. Perhaps an underscore would suit better?